# What exactly will hiding my router's SSID achieve and can all of my devices connect to it?

Tags: windows, mac, wireless-networking, iphone, android

To expand on the title, if I hide my SSID, does this mean devices (excluding advanced network tools) will not be able to see it in a normal WIFI search, or does it mean something else?

Also, if I do hide this, will all of the following devices (which connect fine at the moment) be able to connect okay?

- Windows 7 laptop
- Mac OS X (10.6) laptop
- Android 2.3 phone
- iPhone 4

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding your SSID actually accomplishes very little. Most wireless sniffing tools (Kismet/Kismac) are trivially able to see your SSID anyway. Not broadcasting your SSID does make it harder to configure your devices. They will not be able to manually detect encryption type.

Comment: In addition, we have a couple of devices in our house that absolutely will not see the network when the SSID is hidden. The devices in your list should have no problems either way, but as @JSK NS said, it doesn't accomplish anything to hide it.

Comment: @IanAtkin The devices will only see it if you search for the exact SSID.