# How does disabling SSID broadcast help or doesn't help securing WIFI network

Tags: wifi-configuration

Does disabling of SSID add any level of security to my wifi network at all? As of right now I have it enabled but just wanted to know what changes if i disable it.

Comment: Essentially it keeps noisy neighbors from trying to make random connections.  It really doesn't add any level of security because those using networking tools will still be able to find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly will hiding my router's SSID achieve and can all of my devices connect to it?](http://superuser.com/questions/513636/what-exactly-will-hiding-my-routers-ssid-achieve-and-can-all-of-my-devices-conn)